# Use a class from byte array without reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I've instrumented my class using ASM and processed it like this

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
...
    byte[] classBytes = ... //the class is of type com.mypackage.Test
    Class clazz = defineClass("com.mypackage.Test", classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
    resolveClass(clazz);
    com.mypackage.Test test =(com.mypackage.Test) clazz.newInstance();
```

However I get ClassCastException on the last line:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.Test cannot be cast to com.mypackage.Test
```

The workaround is to use reflection:

```
Object test = clazz.newInstance();
test.getClass().getMethods()[0].invoke(test, null); //invoke some method - successfully
```

Am I using using wrong classloader or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Class.newInstance` is a reflective call.

Typically what you would do in these situations is have the class loader be a child of the class loader that loaded the existing code. Have the implementation class implement an interface from your code's class loader. Use `Class.asSubclass` such that the `Class` is a known subtype of your interface. Construct an instance of the implementation class through `Class.getConstructor.newInstance`.

Using this technique you are not dependent upon using reflection to pick out a method, although it does require a no-args constructor.